# Is there a way to reply to boost::asio::ssl::stream's failure to handshake?

Tags: http, ssl, boost, boost-asio

Say someone is attempting to access my `https` route with `http` or their client doesn't have the proper certificate. I would like my server to be able to send back an error code. Is that not possible?

When the client has the correct cert, I can send them any kind of response I want after the handshake succeeds. But when try to write on the socket after the handshake fails, the client receives none of it, and attempt to close the connection after that doesn't seem to inform the client who is still "refreshing" waiting for said response. If I attempt to close the socket after the handshake fails *without* writing, the client sees it and just says it got ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

So if the handshake fails, is there no nice way to tell the client?

```
void Server::Accept()
{
    std::shared_ptr<socket> sk = CreateSocket();
    acceptor_.async_accept(sk->lowest_layer(),
    [this, sk](boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec) { return; }
        Connection connection = std::make_shared<Connection>(sk, *this);
        if (!connection.IsValid())
        {
            return;
        }

        boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay option(true);
        boost::system::error_code resultCode;
        connection->GetSocket().lowest_layer().set_option(option, resultCode);
        if (resultCode)
        {
            StopConnection(_connection);
            return;
        }

        connection->GetSocket().async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::server, 
[this, connection](const boost::system::error_code &resultCode) {
        if (resultCode)
        {
            // Failed handshake! Doing a Write here, then a close behaves weird on the client.
            // If I just close here, the client just says he didn't get a response.
            connection->Write(errorCode512);
        }
        else
        {
            // Success, I can write whatever I want.
            connection->Start();
        }

    });
}

void Connection::Write(HttpReply reply)
{
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(*m_Socket, ToBuffers(reply),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t)
    {

        boost::system::error_code errorCode;
        m_Socket->lowest_layer().shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both,
        errorCode);
        if(errorCode)
        {
            Log(errorCode.data());
        }

        m_Socket->lowest_layer().close(errorCode);
        if(errorCode)
        {
             Log(errorCode.data());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If the handshake fails, the client would know. In general there's no "nice way" to tell all your clients about all server errors. This is why services have status pages.

Comment: Does it make sense that it says ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE instead of something more relevant?

Comment: Perhaps worth noting the error message of the handshake failure is usually wrong version number